# Is there a way to run the .push() method on an array x number of times? (outside of for loop)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm working on the "Move Zeroes" Leetcode problem. You're asked to move all zeroes to the end of the array, in place, and without changing the order of non-zero elements. My plan is to loop through the array and for each zero splice it to remove, and increment counter by 1. Then push 0 to the array counter(or x) number of times. Here's my code:

```
var moveZeroes = function(nums) {
    let counter = 0
    for (let i =0; i<nums.length; i++) {
        if (nums[i]===0) {
            nums.splice(i,1);
            counter+=1;
        }
    }
    nums.push()
};
```

P.S. I'm trying to avoid a second for loop, or adding the push() into the first for loop. So looking for ways to go about running the push method x number of times outside of for loops. Thank you

Comment: There is a leetcode forum for discussing individual problems there: https://leetcode.com/problems/move-zeroes/discuss. This question would be a better fit there.

Comment: splice is slower than another loop, presumably.

Comment: @NinaScholz splice is already in the for loop. I'm trying to run push() outside of the for loop.

Comment: @Tzvi2 - I think Nina's point is that if you're trying to go faster by avoiding loops and using splice, it's not going to go faster. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's *possible*, sort of, yes, but it's really just hiding another loop (the loop pushing the zeros would be buried in `push`). Basically, you can create an array filled with `0`s and push the contents of that array. You can either do it during:

```
var moveZeroes = function(nums) {
    let counter = 0
    let zeros = [];        // ***
    for (let i =0; i<nums.length; i++) {
        if (nums[i]===0) {
            nums.splice(i,1);
            counter+=1;
            zeros.push(0); // ***
        }
    }
    nums.push(...zeros)    // ***
};
```

or after, but that adds yet another loop:

```
var moveZeroes = function(nums) {
    let counter = 0
    for (let i =0; i<nums.length; i++) {
        if (nums[i]===0) {
            nums.splice(i,1);
            counter+=1;
        }
    }
    nums.push(...Array(counter).fill(0)); // ***
};
```

---

If you want to stick with your `splice` approach, you can `push` as you go rather than afterward:

```
var moveZeroes = function(nums) {
    let counter = 0
    for (let i = 0, l = nums.length; i < l; i++) {
    // −−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    ^^^
        if (nums[i] === 0) {
            nums.splice(i,1);
            nums.push(0);      // ***
            --l                // ***
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Appreciate the thorough answer!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do:

```
nums.push(...Array(counter).fill(0))
```

This uses the possibility of `push` to process multiple arguments, and the spread syntax does the rest (pun intended).

Comment: best answer :) . I was looking for a while for this type of logic. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could take just another approach by using two loops and move in the first loop all not not zero elements and in the second fill the rest with zeros.

```js
var array = [0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0],
    i = 0,
    j = 0;

while (j < array.length) {
    if (array[j] !== 0) array[i++] = array[j];
    j++;
}

while (i < array.length) {
    array[i] = '0';
    i++;
}

console.log(...array);
```